# What to do when Saga Orchestrator fails?

Tags: saga

Let's assume you implement an orchestrated saga. You have an orchestrator, that executes and supervises local transactions on other services.

Now let's assume that the orchestrator goes down in the middle of the saga, right after a saga participant executed a local transaction (and the saga having to process several more local transactions)?

How do the participant and other following participants know that the orchestrator is not available?

Answer (score 2):

Other participants don't need to know that orchestrator is not available. Actually in any pub-sub system subscribers doesn't need to know publishers and vice versa.

IMHO in this situation there is nothing to do other than waiting orchestrator to come up. During the time that orchestrator is not available, domain object should stay in a soft state like "Pending". Of course after orchestrator come up, saga should be finished with success or failure. (eventual consistency)